# Image not displayed after fetching the url in java

Tags: jsp

I got the path of image and i am trying to display it on jsp through  tag but image is bot coming.I have also tried to assign src a static code.Following is my code.

```
 <img alt="" src="c:/indiapod_uploads/uploadedFiles/14RC0199\Desert.jpg" height="20px"width="20px">

 String strUploadPathBase = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"Example\\image-folder\\" ;
 String strfileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
 File file = new File(strUploadPathBase+"uploadedFiles\\"+strPatientNumber+"\\"+strfileName);
```

Please help.

Comment: Try to change the path to relative to the application context.

Comment: I have tried this but now my file is not uploaded

Comment: It looks like you want to display the image that is uploaded by the user. The image file is not part of the application.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is, you need to have a separate Servlet that streams the image file. Map this Servlet to a URL pattern say '/uploaded/*'. In img tag use this path like /uploaded/filename.jpg.

The knowledge of Streams from java.io package and servlet mapping is important here.